# add a verb to a noun without interpose nothing in between

Tags: grammar, verbs, relative-clauses

So I was wondering why in Japanese it's correct to say 寝る時間? Because I thought it was necessary to use the no particle in order to change the noun and add a verb. 
Anyway what grammar is used in phrases like 寝る時間, 食べる時間 and the likes?

Comment: Particle の only joins nouns to other nouns. A verb phrase can directly modify a noun. It's a piece of grammar that is used absolutely everywhere. To learn more try researching 'relative clause' e.g. http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/clause

Answer (score 2):

Verbs can directly modify nouns.  This is similar to the `[NOUN] that [VERBS]` construction in English, only with reversed order, and no need for the "that".

Examples:

- 歩{ある}く人{ひと} -- literally, "walks person" → "person that walks"
- 読{よ}む本{ほん} -- literally, "reads book" → "book that [someone] reads"

When modifying a noun with another noun, you do need the の{no} particle.

- 犬{いぬ}のおもちゃ -- "dog `[POSSESSIVE]` toy" → "dog's toy"
- 携帯{けいたい}のカバー -- "mobile phone `[POSSESSIVE]` cover" → "mobile phone's cover"

Note that, when translating into English, sometimes the `'s` isn't needed: *"dog toy, mobile phone cover"* are also possibly correct, depending on context.